# Difference in Wireless Network

Tags: networking, tcp

AT home, I have 2 devices, one device has the IP address of 10.0.0.2 it's the server and another device which has the IP address of 10.0.0.6

so, on the client code I have this pierce of code

```
  sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    /* Construct the server address structure */
    ServPort=3200;

    servIP="10.0.0.2";

    memset(&ServAddr, 0, sizeof(ServAddr));     /* Zero out structure */
    ServAddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;             /* Internet address family */
    ServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(servIP);   /* Server IP address */
    ServAddr.sin_port        = htons(ServPort); /* Server port */

    /* Establish the connection to the server */
     i= connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &ServAddr, sizeof(ServAddr));
```

I able fully able to connect to the server of 10.0.0.2 from client 10.0.0.6
The code executed successfully.

Then I go to library and now the Server has the IP address 192.168.1.168 and the client device has the IP address 192.168.1.147

so, the code I modified accordingly for the client

```
   sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    /* Construct the server address structure */
    ServPort=3200;

    servIP="192.168.1.168";

    memset(&ServAddr, 0, sizeof(ServAddr));     /* Zero out structure */
    ServAddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;             /* Internet address family */
    ServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(servIP);   /* Server IP address */
    ServAddr.sin_port        = htons(ServPort); /* Server port */

    /* Establish the connection to the server */
     i= connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &ServAddr, sizeof(ServAddr));
```

Now, I not able to connect to the server.

So, I am confused, all the codes are the same, except the IP address of server device and client device.  At home I am able to run the code successfully, but not in the library. this is just TCP, so it should have to do with any firewall.

Comment: It could be a firewall, have you tried to telnet 192.168.1.168 3200 from the client? Could be that the server is configured on a different port too.

Comment: I'd try to use the `ping` and `arp` commands to see if you can resolve the peer. It may be that the router is configured so that peers cannot successfully `arp` each other, thus preventing communications between hosts on the same network who should otherwise be able to communicate. Is the network wired or wireless? If wired, try bringing a small switch (for example, an 8-port) and connect both the devices using the switch. Then the two hosts should be able to communicate regardless of the router configuration, assuming they both get an IP address on the same L3 subnet.

Comment: I checked wireless status of the server device and it's said to be connected to network. I did this   ping 192.168.1.168  the server device. 
PING 192.168.1.168 (192.168.1.168): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: Host is down
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
ping: sendto: Host is down

Comment: @mike why would someone configure the router so that the peers cannot ping or arp each other? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @frogmanx, the server device is my iPhone and the client device is my android.  In my codes, both client and server using 3200 ports. btw how do you telnet from a mobile device to another?

Comment: @lilzz, it's a common feature, especially on "Enterprise" grade wireless networks. For example, see the [Cisco documentation here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/solutions/Enterprise/Mobility/secwlandg20/ch4_2_SPMb.html#wp1307344).

Comment: @lilzz, also, is the iPhone app that is supposed to be the server open? Due to sandboxing restrictions, if you swap out into another app, your server will be suspended. You could test it by using a laptop to try to ping the iPhone and then looking at the ARP table. Then use the command `telnet <server-ip> <server-port>` and see if it connects, or if the connection is refused, or if it times out.

Comment: @mike, "enterprise" grade wireless network can be configured to enable peer to peer  communication right?  For iPhone, TCP is always for Open, however iOS 6 takes away UDP, broadcast no longer working. TCP for iPhone should be good as long as router allows it.

Comment: @lilzz, all I'm saying is it's a *very* common configuration to block communication between wireless peers. Network administrators do it for both privacy reasons and security reasons. Plus they don't necessarily want you taking up all their limited bandwidth doing P2P file sharing. If you don't know for a fact that your wireless network isn't configured to block P2P, you should verify that - either by talking to the network administrator, or yourself by capturing packets. (with 2 laptops running Wireshark you could quickly verify if traffic between the two hosts is blocked)